# Implement notification in BLE

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

How do I implement notification in BLE?

I have a smartphone, and every hour it will send notification to all nearby BLE devices (smartwatch, RFduino, etc) for time synchronization purpose.

Other devices are server now (since it provides data), and smartphone is the client that collect the data.

Could I piggyback into the advertisement packages? For example, the smartphone always broadcast an advertisement packet to annoucement its presence (that's how other devices can find it). Can I modify that packet to be a time sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to send notifications or advertisements, your smartphone has to act as a server, which also means that in order to be able to receive notifications or scan for advertisements, your peripheral devices must act as clients.

This can be a bit tricky, because if two devices act as client and server, they may not simultaneously fulfil the other role. You need to switch roles whenever needed, which is an open field for all kinds of problems.

Also, I am not convinced that it is really the optimal choice to let the smartphone regularly notify all devices in the vicinity. Each of the devices that wants to receive the notification has to be connected with the device in order to receive the notification, and this connection has to be already active when the notification is sent in order to really get the correct time. So all these devices need to connect in advance to the expected notification time, and hold up the connection until the notification has come.

It might be better to just advertise the current time, but remember that you can't connect to the smartphone as a server while it is advertising, because the link layer may not be in scanning and advertising mode at the same time, and you may also not be connected when advertising for a similar reason.

If you want to do it that way, you can include the time information in the advertising data. See the Supplement to the Bluetooth Core Specification v6, Part A for further information on the structure of the advertising data. You could put it in the manufacturer specific data.

However, another option would be to write the time directly to the device using a write request. You can define your own service and characteristics. You can include a "time synch necessary" information in the advertisement data of the servers, and when the smartphone evaluates the advertisement, it can connect to the corresponding device and send the time directly.

The advantage of this procedure is that time is only updated if you really need it on the device, and that you do not have to switch client/server roles, because the device in server role may advertise as normal, and the smartphone can always stay in client role.